# Symfony2 / Search panel on all pages

Tags: forms, symfony

I have search panel(basic form with keyword), now I need to show this form on all pages, how could I do that? If I create action in controller and render

```
{{ render(controller('WebPortalBundle:Default:searchForm')) }}
```

in **::base.html.twig**, form doesn't submit anything.

Could someone advise me with this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symfony create a [sub-request](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel/introduction.html#sub-requests) for it. You should to pass master request object to this action and use it to handle form:

```
{{ render(controller('WebPortalBundle:Default:searchForm', {request: app.request})) }}
```

and in controller do something like:

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function searchFormAction(Request $request)
    {
        // other code...
        $form->handleRequest($request);
    }
}
```